# Sublime Text 3 tab size per file type?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, text-editor

How do I configure the Sublime Text 3 settings so that a specific file type has its own tab size? I want ruby to 2 tab size, python = 4, C++ = 4, etc. How do I do this without manually doing so every time?

Answer (score 66):

Do the following for each file-type:

1- Go to

```
Preferences -> Settings -> More -> Syntax Specific -> User
```

*Note: Might change slightly depending on your OS*

2- `Sublime-Text` will open a file for editing, check the filename: should be called something like `Python.sublime-settings`.

3- Add the following content to the file and save it.

```
{
    "tab_size": 4
}
```

Comment: It has to be done manually for each file type? No plug in or shortcut?

Comment: In my version, it's "Preference" > "Settings - more" > "Syntax specific - User".
Also, it configures the settings for the file type you are currently editing.

Comment: Works like a charm. What I did: (1) open `test.py` -> perform step 1 & 2 above and set `tab_size` to `2`, (2) open `test.js` -> perform step 1 & 2 above and set `tab_size` to `4`. Now whenever a `.py` / `.js` file is opened tab size is `4` and `2` respectively.

Comment: In addition, I'm on a Mac and Sublime Text 3. Step 1 above is slightly different: `Preferences -> Settings - Syntax Specific`. Once clicked into it it takes you directly to `Python-sublime-setting` / `JavaScript-sublime-setting` - depending on which file type you have got it opened in the editor at the point.